# StrongNameError: Has anyone experienced StrongNameErrors with the threads running under W3wp.exe on Windows 2008 Std

Tags: iis-7, windows

I have a web application that runs fine in our loadtest and dev environments, but runs very slow in our production environment. Using procexp64.exe from sysinternals I found threads that reference StrongNameError. This only occurs on our production servers and does not occur on our loadtest or dev servers. The web application on each set of servers is identical (I'm confirmed this multiple times as I'm struggling to resolve this error.

**Example Thread: mscorwks.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo+0x7638**

IIS is configured the same on all servers. The only difference I have been able to discover is the version of Windows. Oddly enough, our loadtest and dev servers are running enterprise and our production servers are running standard.

Is there some little known different between Windows 2008 Standard and Windows 2008 Enterprise that would shed light on this error and possible resolution?

Comment: @Brian: 2 questions: are both servers the same architecture (both 32-bit or both 64-bit)? and do you have symbols properly configured for process explorer?

Comment: Yes both servers are 64 bit.

Comment: I believe the symbols are properly configured. At first I didn't have all the required sysmbols, but downloaded and installed those missing. I'll do a file comparison now to ensure C:\windows\symbols match on both servers.

Comment: I confirmed the correct symbols are infact installed on the production server. A comparison of the symbols of the two servers would not be helpful as the production server is on SP2 and the dev sever is on sp1. If I read this page http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/symbolpkg.mspx correctly, the symbols are different based on service pack level.  Still stumped.

Comment: @Brian: going from SP1 (I assume you mean RTM since there is no 2008 SP1) to SP2 is a much bigger difference than going from Standard to Enterprise, and should probably be noted in your question. Are you positive that the same version of the .Net framework is registered for your IIS site? I don't know how up to date you keep your systems, but 2008 shipped with .Net 2.0 SP1, and 2008SP2 shipped .Net 2.0 SP2. You can of course upgrade them to the same level.

Comment: I wish I could attach a screenshot as the "View basic information about your computer" shows Windows Server Enterprise Service Pack 1. I apologize if calling RTM service pack 1 caused confusion.  Of course SP1 for Windows 2008 wasn’t really released. It is just that Windows Server 2008 RTM was renamed to Windows Server 2008 RTM SP1.

Comment: Production Server -- Windows Server 2008 Standard (x64 without Hyper-V) Service Pack 2 (build 6002) --  Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727.42 -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 3.0.6920.4000  -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319.1

Comment: Development Server -- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise (x64) Service Pack 1 (build 6001) -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727.3053 -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 3.0.6920.1453 -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319.1

Comment: Loadtest Server -- Windows Server 2008 Enterprise Service Pack 2 (build 6002) -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727.4016 -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 3.0.6920.4000 -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 3.5.21022.8 -- Microsoft® .NET Framework Version 4.0.30319.1

Comment: The strong name error does not occur on our load test server either.

Comment: @Brian - what about the version of .Net actually registered for the IIS sites though?

Comment: All of our website on all servers are configured with .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727.  PS: I appreciate your continuing help.

Comment: Could it be that the error has really nothing to do with .net versions, but maybe there is a group policy that is preventing some action thus causing this error. The reason I ask is because our production servers are locked down much more than dev and loadtest. But I'm not even sure where or what to look for.

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing this Brian? I have an IIS worker which has over 100 threads sitting in `StrongNameErrorInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with a very similar problem. My threads are sitting in `clr.dll!StrongNameErrorInfo`. I managed to find [this post](http://souriz.wordpress.com/2008/05/04/bug-in-process-explorer-gift-for-malware/), which suggests that Process Explorer can be wrong about what method the threads are in.